# Interface extensions methods, with matching generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

### Update 1

I realised that the original restriction of a simple generic type meant that I was unable to compare objects of different kinds, regardless of whether they implemented `IComparable<T>` or not, as a result the latest is now:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<TSource, TComparer>(this TSource source, TComparer comparer)
    where TSource : IComparable<TComparer>
    where TComparer : IComparable<TComparer>
{
    return source.CompareTo(comparer) < 0;
}
```

### Original

I've written a simple `IsLessThan(IComparable comparer)` extension method on `IComparable` interface. I've ran into a small *problem* however; I've realised that essentially it allows for any `IComparable` to be compared, which I'd rather not have. Alternatively I'm wondering if it's possible to restrict the parameter using a generic type? Currently my extension method looks like this:

```
public static bool IsLessThan(this IComparable source, IComparable comparer) 
{
    return source.CompareTo(comparer) < 0;
}
```

Is there any way to use generics to ensure that `source` and `comparer` are the same type, whilst still maintaining the constraint of `IComparable`?

### Example

```
int test = 2;
var resultOne = test.IsLessThan(3); // should return true
var resultTwo = test.IsLessThan("Hello world"); // shouldn't compile
```

Comment: You can use `typeof` on both parameters and throw if they are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T source, T comparer) where T : IComparable
```

Or you could make it more constrained, using `IComparable<T>`:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T source, T comparer)
    where T : IComparable<T>
```

The latter would also be more efficient in terms of avoiding boxing.

Comment: Haha, just gave that a go before seeing this, thanks Jon. I didn't realise it would be intelligent enough to put the extension method on the constraint... clever stuff

Comment: Small update; the boxing became a bit of a problem today; in addition to being unable to compare against other types, regardless of the implementation of `IComparable<T>`. I've updated my question to reflect my current solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code

```
public static class ComparableEx
{
    public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T source, T comparer)  
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return source.CompareTo(comparer) < 0;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int test = 2;
        var resultOne = test.IsLessThan(3); // returns true
        var resultTwo = test.IsLessThan("Hello world"); // doesn't compile
    }        
}
```

<sup>I know I am late to the party, but it is an independent solution (plus it's damn hard to compete with Jon, sigh...)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full set of extensions, just to save people time.

I ran a set of 260 unit tests on this using `int` and `DateTime` for `T`, and everything checks out. Don't want to bloat the answer with the test class.

```
using System;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class ComparableExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T source, T comparer)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return source.CompareTo(comparer) < 0;
        }

        public static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(this T source, T comparer)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return source.CompareTo(comparer) > 0;
        }

        public static bool IsEqualTo<T>(this T source, T comparer)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return source.CompareTo(comparer) == 0;
        }

        public static bool IsLessThanOrEqualTo<T>(this T source, T comparer)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return source.CompareTo(comparer) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T>(this T source, T comparer)
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return source.CompareTo(comparer) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```